# In the law of conservation of linear momentum why does the force that body A exert on body B equal the rate of change of momentum of body B?

Tags: conservation-laws

In the law of conservation of linear momentum why does the force that body A (first) exert on body B (second) equal the rate of change of momentum of body B? And why does the force that body B exerts equal the rate of change of momentum of body A?

Answer (score 1):

Force is defined as the rate of change of momentum. You're asking a question a bit like "If I change a bodies linear kinetic energy, why am I changing it's velocity", you just are because those two quantities can be defined by the other.